# Visual Studio 2010 not building header updates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header-files

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C++, and despite setting the precompiled headers option to 'not using precompiled headers' it is still insisting on ignoring my header. On another machine it works fine with the same settings. How can I fix this?

Complex.h

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Complex{

private:
    double real, imaginary, magnitude, angle;
    double rectangularToMagnitude(double, double);
    double rectangularToAngle(double, double);
    double polarToReal(double, double);
    double polarToImaginary(double, double);
public:
    Complex (char, double, double);
    Complex (double, double);
    Complex (double);
    Complex ();

    double getReal();
    double getImaginary();
    double getMagnitude();
    double getAngle();

    void setRectangular(double, double);
    void setPolar(double, double);
};
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include "Complex.h"

// Three arguments passed, type and variables.
Complex::Complex(char type, double a, double b)
{
    switch(type)
    {
    case 'R':
    case 'r':
        setRectangular(a, b);
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        setPolar(a, b);
        break;
    }
}

// Two arguments passed, assume rectangular.
Complex::Complex (double a, double b)
{
    real = a;
    imaginary = b;
    magnitude = rectangularToMagnitude(a, b);
    angle = rectangularToAngle(a, b);
}

// One argument passed, assume real, used to cast double to complex.
Complex::Complex (double a)
{
    real = a;
    imaginary = 0;
    magnitude = a;
    angle = 0;
}

// No argument passed, assume values of zero.
Complex::Complex ()
{
    real = 0;
    imaginary = 0;
    magnitude = 0;
    angle = 0;
}

// Convert real to imaginary and vice versa.
double Complex::rectangularToMagnitude(double re, double im) {return sqrt((re*re)+(im*im));}
double Complex::rectangularToAngle(double re, double im) {return atan2(im, re);}
double Complex::polarToReal(double ma, double an) {return ma*cos(an);}
double Complex::polarToImaginary(double ma, double an) {return ma*sin(an);}

// Accessors
double getReal() {return real;}
double getImaginary() {return imaginary;}
double getMagnitude() {return magnitude;}
double getAngle() {return angle;}

// Mutators
void setRectangular(double re, double im)
{
    real = re;
    imaginary = im;
    magnitude = rectangularToMagnitude(re, im);
    angle = rectangularToAngle(re, im);
}

void setPolar(double ma, double an)
{
    real = polarToReal(ma, an);
    imaginary = polarToImaginary(ma, an);
    magnitude = ma;
    angle = an;
}
```

Errors

```
error C2065: 'real' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'imaginary' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'magnitude' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'angle' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'real' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'imaginary' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'magnitude' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'rectangularToMagnitude': identifier not found
error C2065: 'angle' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'rectangularToAngle': identifier not found
error C2065: 'real' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'polarToReal': identifier not found
error C2065: 'imaginary' : undeclared identifier
error C3861: 'polarToImaginary': identifier not found
error C2065: 'magnitude' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'angle' : undeclared identifier
IntelliSense: identifier "real" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "imaginary" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "magnitude" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "angle" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "real" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "imaginary" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "magnitude" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "rectangularToMagnitude" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "angle" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "rectangularToAngle" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "real" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "polarToReal" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "imaginary" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "polarToImaginary" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "magnitude" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "angle" is undefined
```

Comment: Could you please add the errors you are getting to your question?

Comment: I have 26 undeclared identifier errors where the variables declared in the header file are not being identified. The file built the first time (with schoolboy errors) but after changing the file it is not building anymore.

Comment: Make sure the header is added to the project you are building.

Comment: The header is definitely added, the project built the first time, but when I went to correct MY errors, the header isn't being built anymore.

Comment: When I had similar problems in older versions of Visual Studio, a complete rebuild could help sometimes.

Comment: Code is added to the question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have tried that and unfortunately it's still not building the header! It's not a large program either. I'm 90% certain it's a problem with VS2010 not my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define, for instance, getReal() as Complex::getReal() in your .cpp file.  Also, this is the case for all of your member functions after getReal().

Comment: That was tricky to spot.  But probably easier for someone seeing the code for the first time.